# How to test AD access via Graph at scale

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm building an app in C# that accesses Azure AD data (Calendars) via Graph API.

It works fine with a small Tenant I set up (and pay for) for the purpose.

How can I test at scale - for instance a Tenant with thousands of users - before roll out to live use?

Thanks.

Comment: Outside of trying to test it for real you should do your math and see if based on the number of requests your app makes and what type of authentication is being used is it going to be throttled https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling

Comment: Would be nice for the community if you would accept one of the answers above so people in the future with the same issue would know if this is a solution to the problem

Comment: hello @Repcak, thanks for the nudge. I haven't had a chance to test it yet, also my research suggests I can maybe create users but not calendar items (without every user having a paid licence).

will be back when done.

I appreciate all the responses.

Answer (score 1):

Add dummy/test users to your AAD using powershell:
New-AzAdUser using a for loop

[Here are the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0)

You dont have to assign to them any license. So it won't cost you anything: [Docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/da-dk/pricing/details/active-directory/)
Looks like you can create for free 50,000 objects in the active directory.

Also if you need specific test data for them you have api endpoints for almost anything. You didnt specify what data you would need in the calendars for the users to check.